# read.csv() in R does not produce a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to load data.csv in R using

```
S<-read.csv(file="data.csv")
```

Since it is a single column of numbers (I believe tab deliminated) without header, I was hoping for S to be a vector. But S displays as

```
    X40.87
1    40.69
2    40.94
...   ...
```

(The numbers 40.87,40.69... are my numbers.).
To access the third number, I need to invoke S[2,1]. Why not S[3]?

Comment: Aren't you just missing the header=false bit? `read.csv(file="data.csv",header=FALSE)`

Comment: `scan("data.csv")` will get you a vector.

Comment: The "c" in "CSV" does stand for something you know!? As in *comma* separated values. Your data *can't* be tab delimited otherwise you'd be using `read.table()`. I don't understand the title of your question; R has clearly created a data frame, you expected it to do something different. Hence your title doesn't represent the meat of the question. I believe @billinkc has identified one issue and to get this as a vector, simply index it; `read.csv(file="data.csv", header=FALSE)[,1]`.

Comment: From your question's title, it seems you want a data.frame. From the question's body, it seems you want a vector...

Comment: Title updated to accurately reflect the body o,0

Answer (score 1):

Use `scan()`

```
S <- scan("file.csv")
S[3]
# 40.94
```

Alternatively, as said by billinkc you can use `read.csv("file.csv", header=FALSE)` or just `read.table("file.csv")` as the delimiters aren't relevant in a file with a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Since your CSV has no header, you need to indicate it as such when you open the file the interpreter is going to assign the first row as the column name.

Thus with input file like

```
40.87
40.69
40.94
```

I open this with the same logic you used

```
> s <- read.csv(file="~/Documents/r/data.txt",header=FALSE)
> s
     V1
1 40.87
2 40.69
3 40.94
```

### References

- [read.table {utils}](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want a vector, subset the 1-column data frame:

```
read.csv(file="data.csv", header=FALSE)[,1]
```

This works because of the argument `drop` which takes default `TRUE`, and which *drops* the empty dimension (in this the column information).